# Android ICS - links inside an iframe not working

Tags: php, android, html, web, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have a website in which I am loading some external links using "iframe". Everything works fine in all browsers but in Android ICS, when I click a link inside the iframe page, it redirect to some other page. I googled for some work around and found that there are some ICS specific issue but not found any solution for my issue. Does anyone else face the same issue? And Is there any work around for this issue? Please help.

Comment: In my experience iFrames and android are bitches to each other.

Comment: @Warpzit, Thanks for the comment but Is there any solution to this issue? I cannot apply CSS to the content inside iframe as it is an external link.

Comment: I can't help you. I'm more a native android guy. I ended up doing something completely different so my suggestion to you is to try some more and when you reach a certain point make a fall back solution that is acceptable.